# How to get fail % in sql, when the trials are spread across rows?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table in sql like below

```
Test Run Status
---  --- ---
1    1   Pass
1    2   Fail
2    1   Pass
2    2   Pass
```

I need output like below

```
Test Fail% Pass%
---  ---   ---
1    50%   50%
2    0%    100%
```

How do I achieve this with sql commands only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate function are the key here. and the use of the Case statement to get the conditionals.

```
Select Test, (Sum(CASE when Status = 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)) *100
From mytable
group by test
```